# Where are the new questions?

Tags: support, questions

I apologize if I am delusional and imagined this, but I believe that in a not-so-distant past it was possible to display questions sorted by date so as to get the most recent ones on top of the list. And to achieve this, I selected "new" as opposed to "active" after clicking on the hyperlink "active". Now when I do that, I get active, hot, bounties, week and month. But no sign of "new" anymore.
Sorry if I am late and everyone is up to date regarding this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just go to the "Questions" and then click on "Newest":

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I don't remember having to click on questions first before though, but it works.

Comment: Not [freehand circles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19775#19775) compliant (it has actual practical value).